# SciPy: way to speed up a complicated integral

Tags: performance, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a very complex integral to calculate:

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.integrate import quad, nquad
import numpy as np

alpha = np.array([0.298073, 1.242567, 5.782948, 38.474970])
trial = np.array([0.08704173, 0.52509737, 0.51920929, 0.31233737])


class EigenvalueProblem:

    def __init__(self, a, t):
        self.alpha = a
        self.trial = t

    # Hamiltonian, interaction part
    def hartree_integrand(self, coeff):
        def hartree_potential(rr2):
            return np.array([coeff[ii] * coeff[jj] *
                             np.exp(-(self.alpha[ii] +
                                      self.alpha[jj]) * rr2 ** 2)
                             for ii in range(0, 4) for jj in range(0, 4)]).sum()

        def length(theta, rr1, rr2):
            return 1 / np.sqrt(rr1 ** 2 + rr2 ** 2 -
                               2 * rr1 * rr2 * np.cos(theta))

        def tmp(theta, rr1, rr2):
            return 8 * np.pi ** 2 * rr1 ** 2 * rr2 ** 2 * \
                np.sin(theta) * hartree_potential(rr2) * \
                length(theta, rr1, rr2)

        def integrand(ii, jj, theta, rr1, rr2):
            return np.exp(-(self.alpha[ii] + self.alpha[jj]) * rr1 ** 2) * tmp(theta, rr1, rr2)

        return [
            nquad(lambda theta, rr1, rr2: integrand(i, j, theta, rr1, rr2),
                  [[0, np.pi], [0, np.inf], [0, np.inf]]) for i in range(0, 4) for j in range(0, 4)]


hat = EigenvalueProblem(alpha, trial)
print hat.hartree_integrand(trial)
```

mathematically what I want to calculate is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4waaU.png) (which is the `integrand` function), with paremeters [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjrca.png). However, it takes more than several hours to compute this integral. I wonder is there any method to speed up it? Thank you very much!

Comment: For a start I'd try to rewrite `hartree_potential`.  It's a double loop that generates 16 terms that then get summed to 1.  I bet that can be done without loops, with array calculations using all of `alpha` and `coeff`.

Comment: For clarity I'd rewrite the complicated `lamda` in `nquad` as a function.  It's hard to see what is being evaluated in that double loop.  I guess it's the `nquad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought first to extend limits in integration over r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> to be from -Infinity to +Infinity - extend limits, multiply by 1/2*1/2, etc

Second, switch to use [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature), which is exactly suited to integrate function with e<sup>-x<sup>2</sup></sup> kernels.

Appropriate code is in [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss.html), see references therein